# Why MultipartEntityBuilder throws org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException?

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, jbossfuse, apache-httpcomponents

I have a simple Apache Camel route that gets the serialized files from the queue and sends it to some external resource:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("activemq:alfresco-queue")
        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                multipartEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file", new ByteArrayBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class), 
                        exchange.getIn().getHeader("fileName", String.class)));
                exchange.getIn().setBody(multipartEntityBuilder.build().getContent());              
            }
        })

        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.POST))
        .to("http4://vm-alfce5-31.....com:8080/alfresco/s/someco/queuefileuploader?guest=true")

        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("The response code is: " + 
                        exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Blueprint configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <bean id="myRouteBuilder" class="org.fusesource.example.MyRouteBuilder"/>

    <camelContext id="blueprintContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <routeBuilder ref="myRouteBuilder"/>
    </camelContext>    

</blueprint>
```

My OSGi bundle runs in JBoss FUSE ESB.

When I send files within `1-3 KB` everything works fine. If the file is larger (`4KB`, for example), I get the following error message:

```
Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:63-DP-TAV-51262-1531978204588-1:1:1:1:1 
on ExchangeId: ID-63-DP-TAV-64708-1531973651576-0-3). 
Exhausted after delivery attempt: 
1 caught: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException: 
Content length is too long: 3301060
```

This exception occurs at this call:

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(multipartEntityBuilder.build().getContent());
```

The stacktrace is shown below:

```
org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException: Content length is too long: 3301060
  at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.getContent(MultipartFormEntity.java:103)[commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9 org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-osgi:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2]
  at org.fusesource.example.MyRouteBuilder$2.process(MyRouteBuilder.java:37)[org.fusesource.example:camel-basic:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:112)[org.apache.camel:camel-jms:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:555)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.16.RELEASE_2]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:515)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.16.RELEASE_2]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:485)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.16.RELEASE_2]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.16.RELEASE_2]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.16.RELEASE_2]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.16.RELEASE_2]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.16.RELEASE_2]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:992)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.16.RELEASE_2]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_121]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_121]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_121]
```

Why `MultipartEntityBuilder` throws `org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException`? And where can I set the max size for the passed files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is hard limit of 25kB coded in `MultipartFormEntity#getContent`. Do not use this method for requests, which may exceed this limit, use `HttpEntity#writeTo` instead.

But with Apache Camel you don't need to do it yourself, `HttpEntity` will be converted to `InputStream` automatically in `camel-http4` component.

Set `HttpEntity` to body directly:

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and solved it as following:

```
        // Assuming you created a MultipartEntityBuilder object above
        HttpEntity multipartBody = multipartEntityBuilder.build();

        // Header required to process multipart content
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, multipartBody.getContentType().getValue());

        // MultipartFormEntity#getContent method has a hard limit of 25kB
        if (multipartBody.getContentLength() <= 25 * 1024) {
            exchange.getIn().setBody(multipartBody.getContent());
        }

        // Manually creating input stream to overcome limit
        else {
            final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            multipartBody.writeTo(os);
            os.flush();
            exchange.getIn().setBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()));
        }
```